# Creating nested Java objects from JSON without knowing the class definition

Tags: json, gson

I’ve been trying to use gson to convert the SignalK json into addressable objects, but the challenge I have is that the SignalK definition has different ways of nesting the “Values” element. 
I’ve gotten this to work if I define a class for each way of nesting the “Values” element by using  gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class), but having to define one class for each way of representing the “Values” field seems way to complex. 
Is there a way where I can use gson (or something else) and generate an object runtime that just follows the schema of the json? I’ve tried looking into  generic types with TypeToken, but with no success. 
Here’s two examples of the different “Values” field format:

Example 1:

```
{
"context": "vessels.urn:mrn:signalk:uuid:333037323031",
"updates": [{
        "source": {
            "type": "NMEA0183",
            "talker": "GN",
            "sentence": "RMC",
            "label": "N0183-01"
        },
        "timestamp": "2018-03-21T18:50:31Z",
        "values": [{
                "path": "navigation.position",
                "value": {
                    "longitude": 09.501361,
                    "latitude": 51.763695
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Example 2:

```
{
"context": "vessels.urn:mrn:signalk:uuid:333037323031",
"updates": [{
        "source": {
            "type": "NMEA0183",
            "talker": "GN",
            "sentence": "RMC",
            "label": "N0183-01"
        },
        "timestamp": "2018-03-21T18:50:31Z",
        "values": [{
                "path": "navigation.courseOverGroundTrue",
                "value": 12.236576
            }, {
                "path": "navigation.speedOverGround",
                "value": 5.005144
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're actually looking for a way of matching the `path` representing a type with a `value` value.
[`RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java) exists in the world of Gson to satisfy such a requirement.
This class is not a part of Gson, but you can simply download it and make it a part of your code base to compile it along with the rest of your code.

First off, define a simple value type to represent a position since it's pretty similar to another value type `java.lang.Double` to be used in the example below:

```java
final class Position {

    final double longitude = Double.valueOf(0); // Merely 0 makes javac inline this value to a constant, so we're cheating
    final double latitude = Double.valueOf(0);

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + latitude + ";" + longitude + ")";
    }

}
```

Then, for simplicity, define a simple set of property-reduced mappings:

```java
final class Wrapper {

    final List<Update> updates = null;

}

final class Update {

    final List<AbstractValue<?>> values = null;

}

abstract class AbstractValue<T> {

    final T value = null;

    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

}
```

And now we can define polymorphic values:

```java
final class NavigationPositionValue
        extends AbstractValue<Position> {
}

final class NavigationSpeedOverGroundValue
        extends AbstractValue<Double> {
}

final class NavigationCourseOverGroundTrueValue
        extends AbstractValue<Double> {
}
```

Now, we can map `path` values to their respective expected types and test the built `Gson` instance:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(AbstractValue.class, "path")
                .registerSubtype(NavigationPositionValue.class, "navigation.position")
                .registerSubtype(NavigationCourseOverGroundTrueValue.class, "navigation.courseOverGroundTrue")
                .registerSubtype(NavigationSpeedOverGroundValue.class, "navigation.speedOverGround")
        )
        .create();

public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    for ( final String resourceName : ImmutableList.of("example1.json", "example2.json") ) {
        try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = Resources.getPackageResourceJsonReader(Q49505838.class, resourceName) ) {
            System.out.println(resourceName);
            final Wrapper wrapper = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Wrapper.class);
            for ( final Update update : wrapper.updates ) {
                for ( final Object value : update.values ) {
                    System.out.println("\t" + value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
example1.json
    (51.763695;9.501361)
example2.json
    12.236576
    5.005144
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked very well ! It was a bit difficult to integrate RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory in an elegant way as it wasn't included in the Gson package, but now it's working !